# How to ignore the single and double dot entries in Perl's readdir?

Tags: perl, file, file-io, directory

Following up from here: [Perl Imgsize not working in loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202690/perl-imgsize-not-working-in-loop/21202755?noredirect=1#21202755l)
I have another question - how do I not let perl list the single and double dot entries when it reads the files in a directory?

As in the linked question above, my output to the while loop (`while ($file = readdir($dh))`) is something like this:

```
.
..
file1.jpg
file2.jpg 
file3.jpg 
file4.jpg 
file5.jpg
```

And this creates problems because I've also got a counter somewhere, which is counting my files. And `.` and `..` don't count as files, so my counter is giving a greater number of files in my directories than there really are.

I added `if($file == "." || $file == ".."){ continue;}` and `if ($file ~ /^\./ or $file ~ /^\.\./) {continue;}` and different variations of that to the beginning of the while loop... but I keep getting an abort "due to compilation errors".

How can we get a hold of the single and double dot entries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To test string you have to use `eq`:

```
if($file eq "." || $file eq ".."){ next;}
```

or:

```
next if $file =~ /^\.\.?$/;
```

Comment: The regex `/\A\.\.?\z/` would be better, as this doesn't match the file `"..\n"` which is valid in some filesystems.

Comment: @amon: Thank you, I wasn't aware of that. Could you say what filesystem handles that?

Comment: In the Ext family of filesystems (mostly used on Linux), a filename may contain *any* bytes except `\0` and `/`. The same roughly holds for NTFS, although Windows imposes further restrictions. See also [this comparison of file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits)

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to suggest something else - don't use `readdir` and instead use `glob`.

```
my @dirlist = glob ( "$dir/*.jpg" );
```

And then you'll get a list of *paths* to files matching that spec. This is particularly useful if you're doing:

```
foreach my $file ( glob ( "/path/to/file/*.jpg" ) ) {
     open ( my $input, '<', $file ) or die $!;
}
```

Where with `readdir` you'll only get a filename, and have to reconstruct the path yourself.

Answer (score 3):

If you're getting the directory contents in list context, you can use `grep` to filter out the dotfiles:

```
opendir (my $dh, $src) || die "Can't opendir $src: $!\n";
my @entries = grep {!/^\./} readdir($dh);
closedir ($dh);
```

Comment: OR: `grep /[^\.+]/, list_files( $directory );` doing the negation in the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

this works and skips the first 2 . and ..

```
if($fil !~ m/^\.+/i)
  {
       your stuff here
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have come to another solution, which works for me to delete all files in a subfolder temp - not starting with first file (0) but only with third file (2):

```
#!/bin/perl
@AllFiles = ();
opendir(DIRECTORY, "temp");
@AllFiles = readdir(DIRECTORY);
closedir DIRECTORY;
print $#AllFiles-1  ."\n";                   #Show 3 for three files, as it shows number of last file: 0=. 1=.. 2=aaa.txt 3=bbb.xml 4=ccc.pdf
$FileNumber = 2;                             #Starting with file 2, don't need to try deleting current and parent folders
until($FileNumber > $#AllFiles ) {
    unlink ("temp/" . $AllFiles[$FileNumber]);
    print $FileNumber-1 . ": temp/" . $AllFiles[$FileNumber] . "\n";       #show file numbers as 1=aaa.txt 2=bbb.xml 3=ccc.pdf
    $FileNumber += 1;
}
```