# Passing arguments to system commands from perl

Tags: perl, imagemagick, imagemagick-identify

I'm writing a perl script that uses some ImageMagick commands, specifically identify. The relevant code is here:

```
my $height = system("identify -format %h $curPic");
my $width = system("identify -format %w $curPic");
```

When I run the whole script,it gets hung up on these lines and this is the output:

```
identify: unable to open image 'if0W211.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3323
identify: unable to open image 'if0W211.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3323
```

At first, the problem was related to ImageMagick not have the correct format delegates to work with jpg images, but after fixing that, I'm still getting this error. I can't find any error documentation related to "error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3323". After writing some test code to see what the problem might be, I think I've determined that it has something to do with the way perl passes arguments to system commands, because when I write that system command `identify -format %h xxxx.jpg` in the terminal, it works just fine. I also noticed that when I `print "$curPic\n`, a 256 is prepended to the filename during the print. I don't know why this would be.

For reference, here is how I collect the filenames:

```
opendir DIR, $folder or die "Cannot open directory: $!";
my @files = readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);
```

And here is the full script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use diagnostics;
use File::Copy;

my $folder = "/media/sf_Pictures_from_Reddit";
my $oriFolder = "/media/sf_WrongOrientation";
my $resFolder = "/media/sf_LowRes";

#Collect all the files
opendir DIR, $folder or die "Cannot open directory: $!";
my @files = readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);

#Iterate through each file and check its orientation and resolution
foreach my $curPic (@files) {
    my $height = system("identify -format %h $curPic");
    my $width = system("identify -format %w $curPic");

    #move those that are vertically oriented to a different folder
    if ($height >= ($width*0.8)) {
    move($curPic, $oriFolder//$curPic) or die "The ori move operation     failed for image $curPic: $!";
        print "$curPic was not approved because of its orientation.";
        next;
    }
    #move those that are low res to a third folder
    elsif (($height < 1080) | ($width < 1920)) {
    move($curPic, $resFolder//$curPic) or die "The res move operation     failed for image $curPic: $!";
        print "$curPic was not approved because of its resolution.";
        next;
    }
    print "$curPic is approved as a desktop background";
}
```

EDIT:
I'm switching to the recommended Image::Size library, so here is my updated script. It works for a time, giving me the output I want, but suddenly breaks and says the variables are uninitialized. "Use of uninitialized variable..." There's an error for $height and $width, but once again they both happen after about 20 successful iterations. And it seems to vary if I run the script multiple times back to back.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use diagnostics;
use File::Copy;
use Image::Size;

my $folder = "/media/sf_Pictures_from_Reddit";
my $oriFolder = "/media/sf_WrongOrientation";
my $resFolder = "/media/sf_LowRes";

my $height = 0;
my $width = 0;

#Collect all the files
opendir DIR, $folder or die "Cannot open directory: $!";
my @files = readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);

#Iterate through each file and check its orientation and resolution
foreach my $curPic (@files) {
    ($width, $height) = imgsize("$folder/$curPic");

    #move those that are vertically oriented to a different folder
    if ($height >= ($width*0.8)) {
        move("$folder/$curPic", "$oriFolder/$curPic") or die "The ori move operation failed for image $curPic: $!";
        print "$curPic was not approved because of its orientation.\n";
        next;
    }
    #move those that are low res to a third folder
    elsif (($height < 1080) | ($width < 1920)) {
        move("$folder/$curPic", "$resFolder/$curPic") or die "The res move operation failed for image $curPic: $!";
        print "$curPic was not approved because of its resolution.\n";
        next;
    }
    print "$curPic is approved as a desktop background.\n";
}
```

Comment: Also, use system (or open etc) with a list not a string in order to avoid interpretation inside the shell, e.g. `system('identify','-format','%w',$curPic)`

Comment: By the way, you should print error messages to STDERR (not STDOUT).

Comment: Are you maybe stumbling on `.` and `..`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21203371/2836621

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the message says, you are passing the path to a non-existent file. Instead of passing

```
if0W211.jpg
```

you should be passing

```
/media/sf_Pictures_from_Reddit/if0W211.jpg
```

That still leaves you with the following problems:

- An injection bug
- Possible misinterpretation of the path as an option.
- A lack of error handling
- Lack of capture of the output of the program.
- Repeated executions of an external process.

All these can be fixed by using [Image::Size](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Image::Size) instead.

But if you insist on using `identify`,

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw( capturex );

my $dimensions = eval { capturex("identify", "-format", "%h,%w", "--", "$folder/$curPic") }
    or do {
       warn("Can't determine the dimensions of \"$folder/$curPic\": $@");
       next;
    };

my ($height, $width) = $dimensions =~ /^(\d+),(\d+)$/
   or do {
       warn("Can't determine the dimensions of \"$folder/$curPic\": Unexpected output from \"identify\": $dimensions\n");
       next;
   };
```

If your `identify` doesn't support `--` (or even if it does), you can replace

```
"--", "$folder/$curPic"
```

with

```
"$folder/$curPic" =~ s{^-}{./-}r
```

Comment: I am not that familiar with `capturex` and the `"--"` you have used to separate the filenames from the parameters may be a feature of that, if so, I apologise and will remove this comment. Otherwise though, `identify` itself does not accept `--` as a marker for the end of parameters.

Comment: It tells `identify` the remaining arguments aren't options. Or at least it does on my machine.

Comment: Oh, interesting, under macOS and **ImageMagick** version 7.0.7 if I run `identify -format %h -- a.jpg` I get `identify: unrecognized option "--" @ error/identify.c/IdentifyImageCommand/920.`

Comment: @Mark Setchell, On those, you'd need something like `"$folder/$curPic" =~ s{^-}{./-}r` instead of `"--", "$folder/$curPic"`.

Comment: I just typed it into the Terminal, no Perl involved.

Comment: @Mark Setchell, I was providing the adjustment to my answer needed for your system. It's now in the answer too.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, you are creating two new processes (one to identify the width and another to identify the height) for each and every image, so that potentially causes a considerable load on your system if you have large numbers of images.

As an alternative, you can just invoke one single `identify` process and pass it all the image names, like this:

```
identify -format "%w:%h:%f\n" *jpg
```

**Sample Output**

```
2000:1200:ok.jpg
1200:2000:toolow2.jpg
1000:500:vert.jpg
```

You can then parse that with `bash` or `Perl`:

```
#!/bin/bash

VERT="/tmp"
TOOLOW="/tmp" 

identify -format "%w:%h:%f\n" *jpg | 
   while IFS=: read w h name; do
      echo "DEBUG: $name, $w, $h"
      [[ $h -gt $(( (8*w)/10 )) ]] &&         { mv "$name" "$VERT";   >&2 echo "Too tall: $name"; continue; }
      [[ ($h -lt 1080) || ($w -lt 1920) ]] && { mv "$name" "$TOOLOW"; >&2 echo "Low res: $name";  continue; }
      echo "$name approved"
   done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final script that works for my purposes. I have added definition checks and non-zero checks to make sure that the variables are receiving the proper input before moving forward.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use diagnostics;
use File::Copy;
use Image::Size;

my $folder = "/media/sf_Pictures_from_Reddit";
my $oriFolder = "/media/sf_WrongOrientation";
my $resFolder = "/media/sf_LowRes";

my $height = 0;
my $width = 0;

#Collect all the files
opendir DIR, $folder or die "Cannot open directory: $!";
my @files = readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);

#Iterate through each file and check its orientation and resolution
foreach my $curPic (@files) {

    ($width, $height) = imgsize("$folder/$curPic") or die "Couldn't get the image dimensions for $curPic: $!";

    if($curPic eq "." || $curPic eq ".."){ next;}
    if((defined $height) & (defined $width)){
        if(($height != 0) & ($width != 0)) {

            print "File: $curPic\nHeight: $height\nWidth: $width\n";
            #sleep(0.5);

            #move those that are vertically oriented to a different folder
            if($height >= ($width*0.8)) {
                move("$folder/$curPic", "$oriFolder/$curPic") or die "The ori move operation failed for $curPic: $!";
                print "$curPic was not approved because of its orientation.\n\n";
                next;
            }
            #move those that are low res to a third folder
            elsif(($height < 1080) | ($width < 1920)) {
                move("$folder/$curPic", "$resFolder/$curPic") or die "The res move operation failed for $curPic: $!";
                print "$curPic was not approved because of its resolution.\n\n";
                next;
            }
            print "$curPic is approved as a desktop background.\n\n";
            $height = 0;
            $width = 0;
        }
        else{
            print "Variables failed to initialize.\n\n";
        }
    }
    else{
        print "Variables are undefined.\n\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `elsif` might as well be an `if` as there is a `next` on the alternate preceding branch, it also is missing its second `|`.